# if domain returned from onchange field has no selection values

Tags: odoo, onchange

I want to put domain on Sales Person() that only Sales person for selected Sales Team should be displayed.

For that I have created on_change() on section_id(sales team) and I am returning domain from that method. Though domain is displayed on Sales Person(user_id) when I go to developer mode but no value is displayed over there.

Here is code:

```
def onchange_section_id(self, cr, uid, ids, section_id, context=None):
    crm_case_section_obj = self.pool.get('crm.case.section')
    member_ids = []
    if section_id:
        member_ids = [member_id.id for member_id in crm_case_section_obj.browse(cr, uid, section_id, context=context).member_ids]
    return {'domain': {'user_id': [('user_id', 'in', member_ids)]}}
```

Am i missing something?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: in another way we can put domain like in .xml through take whole tag of core module and palace in your module and give parent object. If you want to show how domain palace than i will give in answer. Because this problem i already face it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you did a little mistake here.

use domain this way: `{'domain': {'user_id': [('id', 'in', member_ids)]}}`

```
def onchange_section_id(self, cr, uid, ids, section_id, context=None):
    crm_case_section_obj = self.pool.get('crm.case.section')
    member_ids = []
    if section_id:
        member_ids = [member_id.id for member_id in crm_case_section_obj.browse(cr, uid, section_id, context=context).member_ids]
    return {'domain': {'user_id': [('id', 'in', member_ids)]}}
```

Comment: not useful. Getting Error. DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "Demo User"
LINE 1: ..._id"."name" IS NULL))  AND  ("res_users"."id" in ('Demo User...

Comment: give your whole traceback, are you learner of openerp, your error show thats thing

Comment: Oops It was mistake from my side. well I found that. yeah It worked. and sorry friend for inconvenience. and your code seems little unfriendly to use. Hope you don't mind if I will edit your answer after all it is to provide better solution.

Comment: hi dear, it not my code, it code's of pooja i justed correct the wrong thing, i am not here to guide people for pep8 rule or correction of code

Comment: I know. Even no one is here to guide pep8 rule. and I was not talking about that kind of change.

Comment: so if it is your mistake remove -1

Comment: I have tried at that time itself but it says that your vote is locked. can only be unloked unless this answer is edited

Comment: Great dear :)    try after some time, if my answer is wrong the you do -1 its not a problem, but if right if you do -1 it throw bad impression to other, first check then do -1, in stack we are to help other not ourself

Comment: I know how it feels. faced same problem before but the difference is I have accepted my mistake. But in my scenario that person has not. anyways there was no bad intention towards you. was just mistake. will take care next time for sure. :)

Comment: and this is rough code so don't take it seriously in case of formatting and all that. :)

Comment: Hello user1576199,  Sorry to disturb u again but had one more problem if i select one Sales Team related Sales persons are filled to Sales Person but if i remove selected sales team in sales person it should show all the sales persons while it is showing me last filtered sales persons.

Comment: def onchange_section_id(self, cr, uid, ids, section_id, context=None):
       if section_id:
            member_ids = [member_id.id for member_id in self.pool.get('crm.case.section').browse(cr, uid, section_id, context=context).member_ids]
            domain =  [('user_id', 'in', member_ids)]
            return {'domain': {'user_id': str([('id', 'in', member_ids)])}}
        return {}

Answer (score 0):

Try this pooja, Hope this will solve your latest problem

```
def onchange_section_id(self, cr, uid, ids, section_id, context=None):
    crm_case_section_obj = self.pool.get('crm.case.section')
    member_ids = []
    if section_id:
        member_ids = [member_id.id for member_id in crm_case_section_obj.browse(cr, uid, section_id, context=context).member_ids]
    return {'domain': {'user_id': [('id', 'in', member_ids)]}, 'value': {'user_id': False}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here didn't work for me, but the comment by user1576199 did.

```
def onchange_section_id(self, cr, uid, ids, section_id, context=None):
    crm_case_section_obj = self.pool.get('crm.case.section')
    member_ids = []
    if section_id:
        member_ids = [member_id.id for member_id in crm_case_section_obj.browse(cr, uid, section_id, context=context).member_ids]
    return {'domain': {'user_id': str([('id', 'in', member_ids)]) }}
```

The trick here is to pass the actual domain as a string, as that's how the web client expects the value for domain. So use **str(** *[('id', in, member_ids)]*  **)**